# How to map multiple network drives based on a users location using powershell?

Tags: powershell, networking, scripting, drive

Trying to create a powershell script to do this but I can't figure out how to code the logic to know which location a user is at and which network drives to map. This will be used for people that travel.

I've been researching and doing trial and error for a little over a week.

```
$AustinShares = @(
    "\\Austin-2016\Austin"
    "\\Austin-2016\PowerCommon"
    )

    $RaleighShares = @(
    "\\Raleigh-2016\PowerCommon"
    "\\Raleigh-2016\Scans"
    "\\Raleigh-2016\PowerProjectControls"
    )

    $AllShares = $AustinShares + $RaleighShares

$apiurl = "http://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=b0639dfc83871399c5d4d122998f0347"

            $apiresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -URI $apiurl

            $hash = @{
                IP = $apiresponse.ip
                Country = $apiresponse.country_name
                RegionName = $apiresponse.region_name
                City = $apiresponse.city
                }

            $result = New-Object PSObject -Property $hash

Write-Output $result

$TestPath = get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk | Select-Object -expand DeviceID -Last 1 |
ForEach-Object { [char]([int][char]$_[0]  + 1) + $_[1] }

If ($apiresponse.region_name -eq $Locations){
    ForEach-Object
    New-PSDrive -Name $TestPath -Root $DrivePath  -Persist -PSProvider "FileSystem"
}
```

So the location API goes out, finds the computer location. I just need to use the state they are in. Based on what state they are in map certain drives for the office in that state. For example if they are in North Carolina map the Raleigh Shares. I think I need to use the "foreach" command but I'm not sure how to incorporate it.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity and clarity, I'm going to assume that you can successfully determine the office, and that you're storing the office name thus found in `$office`, and that you've written a function `Get-NextAvailableDrive` that returns the letter for the next drive to assign:

```
Switch ($office) {
    "Raleigh"    {$sharelist = $RaleighShares}
    "Austin"     {$sharelist = $AustinShares}
# You can add additional office and their shares here as required
}

ForEach ($share in $sharelist) {
    New-PSDrive -Name (Get-NextAvailableDrive) -Root $share -Persist -PSProvider "FileSystem"
}
```

If you add new offices, all you'd have to do is add the office location to the switch, and arrange to have that office's shares listed to be assigned to $sharelist in the switch above.

Comment: I'll also note that if the computers in all of your office are in a domain, you can also use Group Policy to establish needed drive mappings - and that's probably easier.

Comment: We are switching over from using logon scripts to map drives at our main offices to group policy. But for people that travel they will need something dynamic to map drives for each location they go to.

Comment: Also thank you Jeff for figuring all that out. I’m very new to powershell and just couldn’t wrap my mind around how to do this. So say the api spits out that their location is North Carolina. I would need to assign that a variable say $APILocation and I could then use that in place of $office. Also I’m a little confused about using $share how would the script know which “share” to use? If that makes sense?

Comment: Group Policy can also be used to apply to _computers_, not just _users_ - we're doing it here for deciding what network printers are available at a given work site.

Comment: I don’t think our AD is setup with specific sites that I could use with item level targeting. I’ve looked for unique identifiers that I could use in the item level targeting to overcome this issue but haven’t came across any.

Comment: You can create Security Groups (e.g., RaleighComputers and AustinComputers) and just make the respective computers members of the appropriate security group. Then, the mapping policy gets applied based on the location's ...Computers SG. It's really no different from having separate mappings for users who are in sales vs. operations vs. administration.

Comment: What programming languages are you familiar with? If I have a language to relate to, I can probably explain the `ForEach` loop in the code much more clearly.

Comment: And your `$APILocation` would be what I assumed in my code as `$office`; it's a variable that contains the string `Raleigh` or `Austin` or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: Your code that generates the value for `$testpath` - that is, everything from `Get-WMIObject` to the end of that pipeline - is, for all intents and purposes, what I assumed was `Get-NextAvailableDrive`.

Comment: I’ve dabbled in lots of languages but never got a firm understanding of any. But if I had to say 1 it would be C. Don’t worry about explaining the loop. I’ve got a vague understanding but enough to know what it is and how it works. The only other thing I’m confused about is how it knows what each $share in $sharelist is?

Comment: You've assigned the list of shares for the office in the `switch` statement - if the office is Raleigh, then you've assigned `$RaleighShares` to `$sharelist`, and so on. `$share` in the `ForEach` is simply the iterator variable.

Comment: If I were writing this in C, I might write something like `for (share=0; share <= length(sharelist); share++) { map_drive(nextdrive(), sharelist[share]) }` where sharelist is an array of strings containing the share roots, nextdrive() is a function that returns the next available drive letter, and map_drive() is a function that sets up the drive mapping.

Comment: You may find that existing drive mappings need to be deleted before a `New-PSDrive` can be created. When I created it, I could not get `### Remove-PSDrive -Name $mapping.DriveLetter` to work. I ended up using `& cmd.exe /C NET USE $($mapping.DriveLetter + ':') /DEL | Out-Null` to delete the mapping, then `New-PSDrive` to create the new mapping.